# Facebook follow button inside Android webview

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android app which displays facebook's follow button in a webview. URL is below:

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/example&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;fontwidth=450
```

I am also using Facebook SDK for login but unfortunately I am unable to pass login information to the above URL. As a result, "Follow" button leads to facebook login screen after click. Is there a method available by which facebook user id & password or token can be passed to URL of "Follow" button? Please help

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but I could not find anything on "follow" button

Comment: It is for your reference that how to get token/id on login.